# is there anything like (1==0 ? "no" : "yes") in javascript?

Tags: javascript

is there anything like (1==0 ? "no" : "yes") in javascript?

Comment: Undoubtedly you intended to write ( my_var==0 ? ...

Comment: Why haven't you tried it before posting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

JavaScript has the conditional operator, so it's perfectly legitimate to do:

```
var response = (1 == 0 ? "no" : "yes");
```

Comment: I'd refactor that to 
   var response = "yes"; // :)

Comment: Heh. I was future-proofing it for quantum computing where 1 is both 1 and 0 simultaneously! ;-)

Comment: Then you should've refactored it to var response = "yesno";

Answer (score 19):

yes, exactly as you wrote it :)

Comment: easiest 80 rep ever. ;) +1 make it 90.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - it's the [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator), and the syntax is exactly as you've written it.

Comment: Might want to check that link, Jon.

Comment: Thanks John - I think it was a case of hitting 'v' instead of Ctrl-V :)

Comment: Jon, I've got no idea what you were (trying) to link to, I've added a link that is relevant.

Comment: Hmm looks like we edited it at the same time... and it looks like we may have linked to the same place....

Comment: Looks like it, yes :) Without the link it's a pointless answer, but hopefully with the link it's useful...

Comment: Uh oh Jon Skeet answering a Javascript question? Get out of my turf, man! ;)

Comment: @Paolo lol, I still laugh to myself when I see the one question where my answer came in higher then his.

Comment: The thing that bothers me is that it's technically the ternary operator, and even more technically, it's not an operator, it's a structure...

Comment: @Antony: Unless JavaScript is different (and broken :) its name is the conditional operator and it's *a* ternary operator in the same way that / is *a* binary operator. ECMA-262 certainly calls it the conditional operator (see section 11.12).

Comment: (It's a common fallacy in many languages to call the conditional operator "the ternary operator". Why talk about an operator in terms of its arity instead of its purpose? What happens if the language later gains *another* ternary operator?)